# installed android app by 'files by google app' is can't grant 'display over other app' permission

Tags: android, permissions

i develop android app. when i testing my app before release ,build debug or release apk and install my app using files app.
and this app required 'display over other app' permission.

i have problem some device on OS 13 or 14 check permission result was not granted but i already grant  'display over other app' permission and this permission already set grant on special permission setting menu.

but it is not solved by again grant that permission and retry use app.

code for check 'Display over other app' permission in app is like below :

```
private boolean canOverlayPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return false;
}
```

application installed by files app is restric specieal permission ??
or i must installed by only PlayStore  to use special permission??

i need help, please

thank you.

i tried :

1. grant permission again
2. re install app
3. build app to release and install again

i hope my app grant 'display over other app' permission on android OS 13 and 14 Device
( under 12 device is working correct )